# In rails how to take only the show action to a different path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app, I need the add, edit, delete and update paths to be inside admin dash path. I need to put the show path to start from the route url like /products/ID. Here's my routes file :

```
  get '/products/:id', to: 'products#show'

  scope '/dash' do
     resources :products, except: :show
  end
```

Now the problem is when I call `link_to product` in my view, it point to a show path inside the admin dash path like this `dash/products/ID`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you post the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: not sure, but you can try to replace the first line to ``resources :products, only: [:show]``

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. Everything should work with your code. Please, provide `rake routes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the helper url of `get '/products/:id', to: 'products#show'` by running `rake routes` or you can do this instead

```
= link_to "Show", "/products/#{product.id}"
```

Answer (score -1):

`link_to product` looks for `resources :products` in your routes file. That is why its matching the one in scope. There are few ways to fix this issue;

You need to add resources to also outside of scope.

```
  resources :products
  scope '/dash' do
     resources :products, except: :show
  end
```

Or you can name your path and use it in link

```
  get '/products/:id', to: 'products#show', as: 'product'
  scope '/dash' do
     resources :products, except: :show
  end
```

`link_to "Show", product_path(product)`

or you can specify path as in @RSB's answer